# Windows 2003 server + ActiveDirectory

Tags: windows

Не работает "морда" AD. То есть сама служба работает, пускает в домен, регистрирует новую машину в домене, а сам интерфейс нет. Что можно сделать, чтобы интерфейс снова заработал?

Comment: Если Вы дадите больше информации, то возможно, Вам помогут. К примеру, после чего она перестала работать и т.д..

Comment: Сам владею только этой информацией. При попытке запустить оснастку "Пользователи и компьтеры" выходит соссбщение о тм, что сервер нерботоспособен. Даже номера ошибки нет. Возможно, интерфейс и сама AD - это разные службы. Только вот какие, как называются и какой командой запускаются, я не в курсе. Надеюсь на Вас))

Comment: Без более подробного описания проблемы не обойтись. А Вы смотрели настройки соединения с сервером? Возможно в них проблема?

Comment: Антивирус есть?
Удаленно консоль подключаете?

Comment: javer, а что с настройками может быть?
Сергей, поключаю удаленный рабочй стол с учеткой администратора домена. При локальном входе на сервер все тоже самое.

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться sfc /scannow
Если не поможет то выложите логи dcdiag, netdiag, ipconfig /all, не забудьте заменить имя домена в логах и другую секретную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

[ms по этому поводу](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323542). + надо проверить, может фаервол/антивирус в чем-нибудь виновны.

зы. ADSIEdit.msc нормально подключается и работает?

Comment: по поводу MS, посмотрел, там все открыто. ADSIEdit.msc не работает. Говорит, что такого файла нет.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(WS.10).aspx
вот adsiedit :)

Comment: Сори, не знал про него)) Сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: По поводу отсутствия повторяю попробуйте sfc /scannow

Comment: Сергей, спасибо! Пробую) Просто с сервером можно работать в нерабочее время, так как на нем 1с крутится и еще несколько нужных программ

Answer (score 1):

На контроллере домена выполните Dcdiag.exe и покажите его вывод.

Dcdiag может отсутствовать, взять можно с дистрибутива Windows 2003 Server (каталог SupportTools) или [отсюда](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=96a35011-fd83-419d-939b-9a772ea2df90)